# PGSERR and PGPERR Bit Clear

Tags: stm32, can-bus, flash-memory

I have a problem with PGSERR and PGPERR bits being set after reset operation

I am using stm32f4 board than I am using CANBUS and FW update process.

When I use serial debug print in MX_CAN1_Init function. I faced with flash erasing error. Then I analyse that error I found PGSERR and PGPERR bits set.

These bits have to be "0" .

I wanted to analyze this problem so I did these test in my initlize states:

```
    MX_CAN1_Init();
 
 Serialdebugprint("Read PGAERR FLAG %d\n",__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG((FLASH_FLAG_PGPERR)));
 
 Serialdebugprint("Read PGSERR FLAG %d\n",__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG((FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR)));
```

I get this value:

```
Read PGAERR FLAG 64

Read PGSERR FLAG 128
```

I get this value:

Read PGAERR FLAG 64

Read PGSERR FLAG 128

But these flag has to be 0. After the reset.

If I removed the MX_CAN1_Init these flag equals to "0".

When I changed some parameter in the CAN_Init function for example communication speed to 83.3kps to 1Mbs I get this flag as 0 and 128 . By the way when I remove the serialdebug I get the 0 and 128 again.

If I put the MX_CAN1_Init function after a few function than this flag returns "0" .

What is the reason?

```
    /**
 * @brief CAN1 Init function
 * @retval null
 */
 
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{
  CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;
 
  
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 28; //3
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ; //11
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ; //2
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = ENABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
 
    /*##-2- Configure the CAN Filter ###########################################*/
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 0;
 
  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
        // SerialPrint("FILTER ERROR !!");
    Error_Handler();
  }
 
  /*##-3- Start the CAN peripheral ###########################################*/
  if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    // SerialPrint("CAN START ERROR !!");
    /* Start Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
 
  /*##-4- Activate CAN RX notification #######################################*/
  if(HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1,CAN_IT_TX_MAILBOX_EMPTY | CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING |CAN_IT_BUSOFF) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  Serialdebugprint("Success CAN Init \n");
}
```

Serialdebugprint function:

```
void Serialdebugprint(const char *serial_data, ...)
{
  char uartbuffer[1024]="";
  va_list arg;
  va_start(arg, serial_data);
  uint16_t len = vsnprintf(uartbuffer, 1024, serial_data, arg);
  va_end(arg);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)uartbuffer, len, 100);
 
}
```

I think problem start HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)uartbuffer, len, 100) after this line. What is the reason for ?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over this thread when I debugged a related Problem. At some point in my firmware I needed to erase 1 page in the flash of an STM32L496. All I got from the STM HAL was an HAL_ERROR. Further investigations showed that PGSERR Flag was set from a previous flash write process. In the end I found out that the error flag was set because a memset operation to address 0x00.

meaning the PGSERR Flag can be set if you have code like this:

```
uint8_t* pointer; 
memset(pointer, 0x00, 10);
```

btw. there in my case there was no Hartfault when running that code.

Comment: Saw this question after you bumped it by answering. The bug is almost certainly a stack overflow, which in turn will cause similar problems as accessing a random memory location like in your memset example. I posted an answer too about this.

Answer (score 1):

`char uartbuffer[1024]="";` means "please give me a stack overflow asap". Don't declare huge buffers like that on the stack, move them to file scope and/or declare as `static`.

The stack overflow destroys your call stack and pretty much everything else too, after which your code starts to run or access addresses in la-la-land, leading to PGSERR.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you need to add `__HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(0xFF);` before `HAL_FLASH_Unlock();`